# Difference between subset and belong

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is the difference between *subset* and *belong to* ??

And why : A *subset* A is always true and : A *belong to* A is not true ??

Comment: The basic relation is *belongs to* : the number $3$ belongs to the set of *natural* numbers. In term of the basic relation, we can define the relation of *subset of*: a set $A$ is subset of a set $B$ iff every eleemnt of $A$ is an element of $B$. Thus, the set of naturals is subset of the set of *integers*.

Answer (score 2):

$A$ is a subset of $B$ means that every *element* of $A$ is also an element in $B$.

$x$ belongs to $A$ if $x$ is an element of $A$ itself.

Example:
$A = \{1, 2, 3\}$ is a subset of $B = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$, because $1,2$ and $3$ are all elements of $B$.

However, $2$ *belongs* to $B$, and $4$ does not *belong* to $A$.